# Android: Error when many package use R.java

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, package, android-resources

I have two package, for example, `packageA` and `packageB`.
in packageA I has a class named `classA` that take resource from `R.java`: example:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

same with package B. I has a class named `classB` that take resource from `R.java`

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
```

When I want android to run `classB`, I must change `Android Manifest file`, change default package from `com.packageA` to `com.packageB`, so classA will be notice error at above line. The same when I reverse.

So, How can I fixed this problem: use multi packages and many of them use `Resource data`. Please help me.

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the package specified in your manifest is `com.packageA`, then in the files of packageA, you don't need to do anything. In the files of `packageB`, use `import com.packageA.R;` without changing the package name in the manifest. That way, your packageB can access the R.java file.

Comment: Oh. Thanks :) It has solved my error. But my problem continues make me headache :( For example, in `packageA` I have many class. Now, I want first run on `packageB`, so in `android manifest`, I use `com.packageB` and must change each class in `packageA` (Awful !!!). Can you help me ?

Comment: Depending on the version of the SDK tools installed, you may have the ability to change the package name by right clicking on the project, and going to the Android submenu. The Android tools will update most or all of the references to that package, reducing the number you need to change by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to mention all  your packages in the manifest file. Just declare class A package and run the program. But make sure you import the package of class B in your java class where you are calling it. The manifest file by default declares the first package that you mention when you create a new android project.

Let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: Oh. Thanks, It helps me :) But I continue meet problem. For example, in `packageA` I have many class. Now, I want first run on `packageB`, so in `android manifest`, I use `com.packageB` and must change each class in `packageA` (Awful !!!). Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was forking a project to another with different resources, and because I was using scala (2.8.3) and treeshaker, the plug-ins would not allow me to properly use android library projects.

I solved the problem by adding a custom build step with ant which creates a duplicate of R.java in the package I wanted.

I added a file named `custom_rules.xml` to the root of my project MyProjectExtended with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project name="MyProjectExtended" default="debug">
  <condition property="exe" value=".exe" else=""><os family="windows" /></condition>
  <property name="aapt" location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt${exe}" />
  <property name="android.jar" location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar" />

  <!-- Generates the R.java file for this project's resources. -->
  <target name="debug">
     <echo>Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...</echo>
 <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="package" />
   <arg line="" />
   <arg value="-m" />
   <arg value="-J" />
   <arg path="gen" />
   <arg value="-M" />
   <arg path="AndroidManifest.xml" />
   <arg value="-S" />
   <arg path="res" />
   <arg value="-I" />
   <arg path="${android.jar}" />
   <arg value="--custom-package" />
   <arg value="com.MyProjectExtendedPackage" />
     </exec>  
  </target>
</project>
```

Then I added the custom build step:

- Right-click on the project, properties
- On the "Builder", click on "New ..."
- Choose "Ant Builder", continue.
- For the BuildFile `${workspace_loc:/MyProjectExtended/custom_rules.xml}`
- Base directory : `${workspace_loc:/MyProjectExtended}`

and if the console pop-up is annoying, you can disable it in the tab named 'Build Options'